# call of java mutator sort on immutable kotlin collection

Tags: android, kotlin, sorting, testing, arraylist

Getting "call of java mutator sort on immutable kotlin collection" as a warning in Android Studio. What could be the reason behind it and how can I resolve it ?

My code looks like this:

```
 @Test
fun test_Sorting() {
    val longs = listOf(10, 9, 7, 3, 2, -1, 5, 1, 65, -656)
    val uniqueList = UniqueArrayList.from(longs)
    Collections.sort(longs) // **getting the warning on this particular line**
    uniqueList.sort()
    assertListEquals(longs, uniqueList)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin has two types of list

- The read-only `List` interface (Java doesn't have this)
- The `MutableList` interface, a subtype of `List` and equivalent with Java's `List`.

In Kotlin, you cannot mutate a read-only List because it doesn't have any exposed functions for doing so. But if you pass it to a Java-defined method, the compiler will automatically cast it to Java's *mutable* `List` interface for interoperability purposes.

The warning is telling you that you are accidentally mutating a List that should be read-only. This can create bugs if your code elsewhere assumes that this List will not be mutated, which is generally a safe assumption for whatever scope of code generated the list.

In this particular case, the code will actually succeed at runtime because the underlying list returned by `listOf()` with multiple values is actually an `ArrayList`, which is mutable, but has been upcast to read-only `List`. However, some of the ways of creating a read-only `List` in Kotlin produce truly *immutable* lists that will throw an exception if you try to mutate them.

The warning message is actually misleading, and in my opinion should be rephrased to say "read-only List" instead of "immutable List"

If you want to safely be able to sort a List in Kotlin, you must declare it as mutable to begin with:

```
val longs = mutableListOf(10, 9, 7, 3, 2, -1, 5, 1, 65, -656)
```